# What's the Pal Points limit?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

Pal Points can be used at the Pal Egg Machine. What's the maximum amount of Pal Points? How many rolls is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

25,000 is the Pal Points limit. That's 50 rolls.

> The maximum value of Pal Points that players can hold will change from 20,000 to 25,000.
>
> *If a player’s Pal Points exceed the limit, they will be unable to add further Pal Points from in-game mails.

- Puzzle & Dragons (North America) - GungHo, 10 March 2016, https://m.facebook.com/notes/puzzle-dragons-north-america-gungho/version-87-patch-notes/1238005342894722/